# Spring Thymeleaf - How do I find an object id from html and pass the id to the controller?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my html I display all my assignment, exam and attendance objects. I want to find the ids of those objects and pass it over to the controller because I want the user to be able to edit those objects and in order to do that I need to find their id. The button to edit the object will be beside the objects name. That is how I want to do it anyway.

Here is my HTML:

```
div th:each="subject : ${subjects}">
   Subject: <h4 th:text="${subject.subjectName}" />
 /

<h4> assignments:</h4>
<div th:each="assignment : ${subject.assignment}">
<h4 th:text="${assignment.assignmentTitle}"/>
</div>
<h4> exams:</h4>
<div th:each="exam : ${subject.exam}"> 
<h4 th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/>
<h4 th:text="${exam.examId}"/>
</div>
<h4>Attendance:</h4>
<div th:each="attendance : ${subject.attendance}">
<h4 th:text="${attendance.attendanceTitle}"/>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/allSubjects")
public String shoSubjects(@ModelAttribute("subject") @Valid UserRegistrationDto userDto, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String email = loggedInUser.getName();   


    User user = userRepository.findByEmailAddress(email);
    List<Subject> subjects = user.getSubject();

    model.addAttribute("subjects", user.getSubject());
```

Comment: you can add the id for each object as an attribute, where is your problem?

Comment: @cralfaro I don't understand what you mean. The users objects will be displayed on the HTML page and the user will select one to edit. I want to find the ID of the one they selected and pass that ID over to the controller.

Comment: You already have the ID -- in expressions like `<h4 th:text="${exam.examId}"/>`.  You just make a url that has the id in it.  Something like: `<a th:href="@{edit_exam.html(id=${exam.examId})}">Edit Exam</a>`.

Comment: @Metroids Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I was able to find the ID of the exam that the user selected to edit and it brings them to the edit HTML page.

My HTML:

```
<h4> exams:</h4>
<div th:each="exam : ${subject.exam}"> 
<h4 th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/>

<a th:href="@{/editExam.html(id=${exam.examId})}">Edit Exam</a>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editExam.html{examId}", method =RequestMethod.GET)
public String editExam(@PathVariable String examId) {

    return "editExam";
}
```